# Adding a triangle to the top of div as it appears in tooltip?

Tags: html, css

I have the div which will be shown on hover of some element. the div which will display when we hover on element is displayed below the element. I need to add the triangle `/\` to the top of div using css.

How can I achieve this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="user-options">
        <ul class="settings">
            <li><a href="home.html">JOHN DOE</a></li>
            <li><a href="user-customization.html">My Playground</a></li>
            <li><a href="myrules.html">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.user > .user-options {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eeeeee;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 25px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 125px;
    z-index: 999;
    border:solid #cccccc 1px;
    margin-left:-24px;
}
```

Comment: You can use this online tool: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: The link to "How do CSS triangles work?" isn't correct as this is slightly different. It is adding a triangle to a div, not just making a triangle.

Comment: Complete tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

Note: remove the `overflow: auto;` from `.user-options`

**CSS**

```
.user-options {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eeeeee;
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 125px;
    z-index: 999;
    border:solid #cccccc 1px;
    margin-left:-24px;
}

.user-options:after, .user-options:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.user-options:after {
    border-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #eeeeee;
    border-width: 15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.user-options:before {
    border-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #cccccc;
    border-width: 16px;
    margin-left: -16px;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nxgw3kdo/16/)**

Answer (score 1):

I would use the this, depends if you want a border round the triangle though. If so you want to use both `:before` and `:after`.

```css
.user-options {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eeeeee;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 125px;
  z-index: 999;
  border: solid #cccccc 1px;
  margin-left: -24px;
}
.user-options:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 12px;
  border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
  left: 15%;
  /* TOP IS DOUBLE THE HEIGHT OF THE BORDER */
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-options">
  <ul class="settings">
    <li><a href="home.html">JOHN DOE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="user-customization.html">My Playground</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="myrules.html">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give following way:

```css
.user-options {
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid #cccccc;
  top: 100px;
}
.user-options:after,
.arrow_box:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 20%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
}
.user-options:after {
  border-bottom-color: #cccccc;
  border-width: 30px;
}
.user-options:before {
  border-bottom-color: #cccccc;
  border-width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-options">
  <ul class="settings">
    <li><a href="home.html">JOHN DOE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="user-customization.html">My Playground</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="myrules.html">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/nxgw3kdo/17/)